# Getting acces to host VM in a VirtualBox with Puppet

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, puppet

I have an application running in a VirtualBox VM that for testing purposes needs to connect to the host machine. The VM is started with Vagrant and managed by Puppet.

What is the best way to set-up this connection? For example, om my host machine the app runs on port 9200. So from my VM I'd like to go to `myhostmachine:9200`.

Currently I'm thinking of hacking in a small command that adds `hostvm` as a entry to `/etc/hosts` using a simple command like this to figure out my host ip (which is the same as the default route).

```
/sbin/ip -4 route list 0/0 | grep -m 1 default | awk '/default/ { print $3 }'
```

And just let Puppet run that every time using the `exec` functionality. However, I get the feeling there has to be a better way.

The guest OS is Ubuntu 12.04 and the Host is OS-X.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is related to this one, but the point is I'm not sure 10.0.2.2 is always available: http://superuser.com/questions/144453/virtualbox-guest-os-accessing-local-server-on-host-os

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, at the moment Vagrant [always](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2093) sets up a natted interface to connect to virtualbox, so I think that the ip of your host machine will always be the 10.0.2.2 address you mentioned.  I reckon a puppet host declaration might be easier to manage than running that command each time.

```
host { 'myhostmachine':
  ip => '10.0.2.2',
}
```

The puppet [resource reference](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#host) for hosts has all the other params you can set too.

I was then able to access the host using myhostmachine:9200

Comment: Yes, and you could likely leverage the `$::ipaddress` facts and/or its ilk to make this even more automagic.